# How to get DataTemplate key using code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a DataTemplate as follows

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ScheduleItemPendingTemplate">
    <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False" Background="{StaticResource StatusPendingBrush}">

        <Rectangle Stroke="{StaticResource AppointmentSectionBgActive}"
                   StrokeDashArray="2 1"
                   StrokeThickness="1.5"
                   Fill="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderBackground}" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="txtAppointmentTitleinDefault"
                       Text="{x:Static resource:StringResources.Label_AppointmentStatus_Pending}"

                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Style="{StaticResource AppointmentDataLabel}" />

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have assigned this template to a DataTemplate variable using below code.

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{   
      dataTemplate = AppointmentTemplateResourceDictionary["DefaultTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
      if (//some condition)
      {
          DataTemplate pendingTemplate = AppointmentTemplateResourceDictionary["ScheduleItemPendingTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
      }
      return pendingTemplate;
 }
```

How can I know that the name of the DataTemplate which I have returned?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx

And the code somewhere inside of you control

```
var = this.FindResource("ResourceKey")
```

Comment: FinResource is used to find inside a dictionary. I want the DataTemplate key which I holds

Comment: @VimalCK Holds where?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to get `x:Key` in code behind if you are already aware of it. `x:Key` will be `ScheduleItemPendingTemplate`.

And regarding `DataTemplateKey`, it is used to identify `DataType` of DataTemplate and `will be null in case you haven't defined any DataType for your template`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ScheduleItemPendingTemplate"
              DataType="StackPanel">
   ....
</DataTemplate>
```

In above case `DataTemplateKey` won't be null and will tell you that it's DataType is StackPanel.

Also there is no way to get `x:Key` from code behind. Only way to get is to loop over Resource keys -

```
foreach (var resourceKey in this.Resources.Keys)
{

}
```

---

As mentioned there is nothing inbuilt which can get you `x:Key` from DataTemplate. But you can add resource at runtime and can access `Resources` where you want to fetch this name. **(This is workaround only)**

```
dataTemplate = AppointmentTemplateResourceDictionary["DefaultTemplate"]
                     as DataTemplate;
dataTemplate.Resources["Key"] = "DefaultTemplate";
if (//some condition)
{
   DataTemplate pendingTemplate = 
          AppointmentTemplateResourceDictionary["ScheduleItemPendingTemplate"]
             as DataTemplate;
   pendingTemplate.Resources["Key"] = "ScheduleItemPendingTemplate";
}
```

and you can access it like this where you want -

```
string key = dataTemplate.Resources["Key"];
```

Comment: I still don't see why you need to care about it. But any ways if you still need it you can pass parameter as `out` and set value for that parameter in method which will be available to outside world.

Comment: I have returning the DataTemplate based on a condition in SelectTemplate method. I want to know the returnDataTemplate key value. It is not possible to use ref keyword or changing the method signature. Any way

Comment: Sorry but there is nothing in `DataTemplate` class which can tell you `x:Key` associated with template.

Comment: exactly.. the same I am looking for... :(

Comment: I have update with some workaround. See if that helps.